# How to Delete Item From Listview on Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to delete item when I long clicked. First ı want to get position and then ı want to remove any item.
My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final List<Kisi> kisiler = new ArrayList<Kisi>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        kisiler.add(new Kisi("Ahmet Yılmaz", false, 0));
        kisiler.add(new Kisi("Ayşe Küçük", true, 1));
        kisiler.add(new Kisi("Fatma Bulgurcu", true, 2));
        kisiler.add(new Kisi("İzzet Altınmeşe", false, 3));
        kisiler.add(new Kisi("Melek Subaşı", true, 4));
        kisiler.add(new Kisi("Selim Serdilli", false, 5));
        kisiler.add(new Kisi("Halil İbrahim", false, 6));

        final ListView listemiz = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);
        final ozelAdapter adaptorumuz = new ozelAdapter(this, kisiler);
        listemiz.setAdapter(adaptorumuz);
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
package com.endroidteam.customlistview;


public class ozelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Kisi> mKisiListesi;

    public  ozelAdapter(Activity activity, List<Kisi> kisiler) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mKisiListesi = kisiler;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mKisiListesi.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mKisiListesi.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View satirView;

        satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.satir, null);
        TextView textView =
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.isimsoyisim);
        ImageView imageView =
                (ImageView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.simge);

        Kisi kisi = mKisiListesi.get(position);
        textView.setText(kisi.getIsim());

        if (kisi.isKadinMi()) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_icon_big_13);
        }
        else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_icon_big_4);
        }
        return satirView;
    }
}
```

My GetterSetter:

```
  private String isim;
    private boolean kadinMi;
    private int konum;


    public Kisi(String isim, boolean kadinMi, int konum) {
        super();
        this.isim = isim;
        this.kadinMi = kadinMi;
        this.konum = konum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return isim;
    }

    public String getIsim() {
        return isim;
    }

    public void setIsim(String isim) {
    this.isim = isim;
    }

    public  int getKonum()  {
        return konum;
    }

    public void setKonum(int konum) {
        this.konum = konum;
    }

    public boolean isKadinMi() {
        return kadinMi;
    }

    public void setKadinMi(boolean kadinMi) {
        this.kadinMi = kadinMi;
    }
}
```

Please help me how can I remove the selected item from the following listview:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to remove an item on the list when it gets button press - In the function where the button press gets called, get item position and remove the item like so:

```
this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Do some
    return true;
}
```

});

```
kissiler.remove(position)
```

and then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

That will solve your problem.

Full code:

```
this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Do some
    kissiler.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}});
```

EDIT: I made a terrible mistake and used id instead of position - obviously you'll have to use the position variable in the functions parameters as it gives an integer where the item is located in your listview.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know exactly how can ı get item id

Comment: @EmreTekin When the function I described above gets called it sends the id of the listview item thats clicked on to the variable id in the function parameters.

Comment: @EmreTekin I made a mistake in my code and have corrected it. Try it now.

Comment: How to delete the selected item from database. The problem is, when ever i come back to my app, the deleted items were appearing again.

Answer (score 0):

remove the elements from your adapter and notify the listView with

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```